# How to insert records into SQL server from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am not great at programming but I am getting by and I just want to update a sheet in excel into a table in SQL server 2012.

I can create the connection, insert HARD values but for some reason I cannot figure out how to insert ranges.

That is, the following code works fine:

```
objConnection.Execute "USE database1 INSERT INTO tblExposure(AssetID, Name) VALUES  (1234, 'Metoo')"
```

But, when I try to substitute a range, like `Range.("A3").Value`, I cant get it working.

```
objConnection.Execute "USE database1 INSERT INTO tblExposure(AssetID, Name) VALUES  (Range("A3").Value, 'Metoo')"
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: _i cant get it working_ is not a good description of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the range outside the quotes:

```
"USE database1 INSERT INTO tblExposure(AssetID, Name) VALUES  (" _
   & Range("A3").Value & ", 'Metoo')"
```